# Does this type of tripartite graph formed from two $K_{2,4}$'s have a name?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, bipartite-graphs, neural-networks

This tri-partite graph is a $K_{4,2}$ (blue) followed by another $K_{4,2}$  (red):

[image]

I used red and blue just because when I used blue both times, it might look like some of the leftmost vertices are connected to some of the rightmost ones, which isn't the case.

Do such graphs have a name such as $K_{4,2/4,2}$ or something?
The graph is definitely not random, there's a simple formula to make such a graph.

Comment: That's true, but it is a very special subgraph of K4,6K4,6: a tri-partite graph with a repeating pattern. My application isn't neural-networks, but this type of graph comes up enormously in neural networks: here's a "complete graph" version: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network#/media/File:Colored_neural_network.svg

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1930797/202425) claims that it's a subset of a graph called an "artificial neural network" although I've never seen seen a graph called that, especially outside of the context of neural netowrks (I'm not working in neural networks). Anyway, the thing I gave is a very specific graph, definitely not just a bunch random edges, so I hope someone might come up with something.

Comment: Is someone perhaps able to move this to "artificial intelligence" or "cross-validated (machine learning)" if they think it would be appropriate?